# How to define simple global function in soap ui for use by every mock operation or service (groovy scripting)?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have some common code that gets called while processing the response for every mock operation in a mock service in SOAP UI.

How and where can i define a public globally accessible function so that i can remove code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the function in a separate script file with a .groovy extension and save this script in the scripts folder , this is in the directory where SOAP UI is installed.

> SoapUI Pro adds the possibility to have a central library of Groovy
>   Classes that can be accessed from any script within SoapUI, which can
>   be useful for centralizing common tasks and functionality and for
>   creating SoapUI extensions. Use as follows:
>
> - Specify which folder to use in the SoapUI Pro Preferences tab    (default is /scripts). SoapUI Pro will check this folder for files
>     with the "Groovy" extension and compile these upon startup. The
>     folder is then checked periodically (every 5 seconds) for updates and 
>     new or existing scripts are compiled and re-compiled if necessary.
> - Scripts should be placed in folders named after their containing       package, ie a script in the package soapui.demo should be in a
>     soapui/demo folder under the specified scripts folder.
> - The compiled classes are added to the parent class loader of all       Groovy scripts, you can access them as standard java classes.

You can read more [here](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, firstly you need to create project as below,

```
soapUI Project
|__ Test Suite
   |__Test Case
      |__Test Steps
         |__Global Groovy Script
         |__Mock Response 1
         |__Mock Response 2
```

So, within the "Global Groovy Script", you can create accessible function. Please notice that you cannot access the function from different test case.

Comment: This does not work for me with SoapUI OSS 5.0. Example, I create a first Groovy teststep with a method "public void myMethod() { log.info "hello world";} and then try to invoke myMethod in a later teststep in the same testcase leads to compilation errors in the later teststep (groovy.lang.MissingMethodException).